# SagePay Response Issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, opayo

I am trying to integrate the sagePay in an ASP.NET MVC project. I used Iframe mode of the SagePay.
After I submit the credit card details using pay button, I am able to get response to my notification Controller (Which I sent us the notification URL) with a message **"0000: The Authorization is successfull"** and **WasTransactionSuccessful as true**.

Controller Code:

```
public ActionResult Notify(SagePayResponse response)
        {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.VendorTxCode))
            {
                return new ErrorResult();
            }

            if (response.WasTransactionSuccessful)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Success", new { vendorTxCode = response.VendorTxCode });
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Failed", new { vendorTxCode = response.VendorTxCode });
            }
        }
```

The same controller has called **five times repeatedly** with same values.

[image]

However the final response comes with an error **"5004 : The transaction state is invalid"**. And the variable **WasTransactionSuccessful is false**. As give in the image.

[image]

Finally I believe because of these errors I get following error in the same page which the IFrame is included.

[image]

After seven to eight minutes, my PaymentResponse Controller again got called with the error message **"2008: The transaction timed out"**.

[image]

Please help me to find out the actual cause of this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved there was an extra field for USA country users need to pass, that is the State Code, That was missing.